# Angular 5 : Different foreground color for select list option text

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

I want to color the foreground of select list options with different colors :
Following is the code for my dropdown :

```
<select id="tier" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tierId">
    <option *ngFor="let m of tierList" value="{{m.tier}}" >
        {{m.optiontext}} | {{m.count}} 
    </option>
</select>
```

I want to show optiontext in blue color and count in red color. Is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Comment: have them in different html elements like `span` and apply them a class.

Comment: I ended up using material component as suggested by @Hefe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `<select>` doesn't support multiple colors in an option.

You could try other libraries, such as @angular/material.

for example:

```
<mat-select id="tier" [(value)]="tierId">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let m of tierList" [value]="m.tier">
    <span style="color: blue;">{{m.optiontext}}</span> |
    <span style="color: red;">{{m.count}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

for more information, see https://v5.material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         option.red {
             background-color:red
          }
         option.blue {
             background-color:blue
         }
         option.white {
             background-color:white
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <select>
      <option value="item 1" class="red">Item 1</option>
      <option value="item 2" class="blue">Item 2</option>
      <option value="item 3" class="white">Item 3</option>
   </select>
</html>
```

Comment: what about `forloop`?

Comment: I'm in hurry, it's just that you can use class or [ngClass] to change the background of select options